# Adding more data attributes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to add HTML5 data-* values with jQuery and nothing seems to be happening, am I doing anything wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-js="click-chat"></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('[data-js=click-chat]').click(function(){
    $(this).data("role",'test')
})
```

For some reason it isn't setting any data, or updating the existing value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .attr property like this

```
$(this).attr('id', 'your-id-value');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `.data()` does not create an attribute, it simply adds data to the element. You should be able to use it using `.data('role')`, but you will not see an attribute in html.

So if you call `.data()` on a selector it will check for `data-` attributes as well as check for data not present in attribute-form.

Comment: Thanks! How would I be able to add another value to the data-js attribute? so I get [data-js=click-chat something]

Comment: using .attr('data-js', 'some value');

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.attr()` method if you want to add an attribute to your element.
Otherwise all of the other answers are correct with how `data()` works.

```
 $('a[data-js="click-chat"').attr('data-monkey', "lemur");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `.data()` function jQuery doesn't store the values as actual attributes on the element, so you won't see any changes to the DOM. The first time you call `.data()` it stores the current values of any `data-*` attributes on the element(s) internally, then uses that store to get or set values for any subsequent calls.

This isn't consistent with using `.attr('data-*')` since that *does* work with the actual attributes defined on the elements, so you want to use one or the other.